# Method Not Allowed (POST): /experience/create-review/

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a view that would add a review to a specific product in my Django app but I keep getting a 405 error `Method Not Allowed`.

2 of us tried to solve this but couldn't achieve anything..

Here's what we've been trying so far:

Models.py;

```
class Review(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

  product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

  review = models.TextField()
  is_positive = models.BooleanField()

  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


  class Meta:
      unique_together = (('user', 'product'),)

  def __str__(self):
      return '{}'.format(self.review)
```

Views.py;

```
class ReviewCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOnlyMixin, CreateView):
model = Review
fields = ['user', 'product', 'review', 'is_positive']
template = "product.html"

def get_success_url(self):
    kwargs = {'slug': self.object.product.slug}
    url = reverse_lazy("experience", kwargs=kwargs)
    return url
```

Urls.py (no duplicates found);

```
url(r'^experience/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductView.as_view(), name='experience'),
url(r'^experience/create-review/$', ReviewCreate.as_view(), name='add-review'),
url(r'^reservation/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', BookingView.as_view(), name='booking'),
```

and in the template product.html;

```
<form action="{% url 'add-review' %}" class="writearev-form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ object.pk }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ user.userprofile.pk }}">
    <label class="control control--radio control-one">
       <input value="true" id="chkTrue" type="radio" name="is_positive">Avis positif
       <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--radio control-two">
       <input value="false" id="chkFalse" type="radio" name="is_positive">Avis négatif
       <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <textarea name="review" for="writearev-label" type="textarea" class="input-writearev" placeholder="Rédiger votre avis.."></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-writearev">Publier</button>
 </form>
```

How can this be fixed?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`add-review`** view must be placed in the top of **`experience`**. In your case, the **`create-review`** will match with **`[\w-]+`** and Django will try to send a POST request to `experience` view.

```
url(r'^experience/create-review/$', ReviewCreate.as_view(), name='add-review'),
url(r'^experience/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductView.as_view(), name='experience'),
url(r'^reservation/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', experienceBookingView.as_view(), name='booking'),
```